# Domain name displayed to end-users when using Azure Web Apps and CDN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco, azure-cdn, umbraco8

**Environment**

- Application: Umbraco (brochure site, no login/interaction, simple contact form only)
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows with .NET 4.7 (not Docker)
- App Configuration: Azure Web App (P1V2) (standard/default configuration, e.g., no custom domain)
- Database Configuration: S2 (standard/default configuration, e.g., single region)
- Storage: Premium (standard/default configuration, e.g., no CDN)
- CDN: Custom domain (mywebsite.com >>CNAME>> mywebsite.azureedge.net)

The Umbraco web site/app is running and performing as expected. However, when browsing the site, the domain "mywebsite.com" keeps changing to "mywebsite-com.azurewebsites.net" (the URL of the web-app) rather than remaining as "mywebsite.com". The desired configuration is for the "mywebsite.com" **only** to be used (and therefore utilising the CDN) and displayed in the end-user browser.

I would like to know whether someone has experienced a similar issue and is this something which needs to be changed in Umbraco or Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set up the hostname in Umbraco? If not, try that.
[image]

Add new Domain (your mywebsite.com) and Umbraco will use that for all internal links.

Comment: Yes, I have set that up and there is no change. I have also updated umbracoApplicationUrl in umbracoSettings.config and the rewrite rules in web.config but again no change.